# List Comprehensions break inner loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

```
keyword = ['air','water' ,'fire','earth']
actual = ['air','water earth']
new = []

for a in actual:
    for k in keyword:
        if k in a:
           new.append(a)
           break

print("\n".join(new))
#air
#water earth
```

if without the `break`, it will print

```
#air
#water earth
#water earth
```

How can I convert it into list comprehension and with the keyword `break`?

My code are

```
[new.append(a) for a in actual for k in keyword if k in a]
```

Please help me for this.

Comment: what are you trying to do?
"air" in "air" what check is this?

Comment: you do not need append in list comprehension

Comment: can you be please more specific on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change how you consider your condition, e.g.:

```
In []:
new = [a for a in actual if any(k in a for k in keyword)]
print(new)

Out[]:
['air', 'water earth']
```

This in long form would be:

```
new = []
for a in actual:
    if any(k in a for k in keywords):
        new.append(a)
```

Which is functionally equivalent to the inner loop with the break, because `any()` will short circuit.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that makes you realize how beautiful a language Python really is.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. I will just make it `[new.append(a) for a in actual if any(k in a for k in keyword)]`, so I no need to go through another loop, it can save the processing time

Comment: You shouldn't do `new.append()` in the comprehension, just `new = [a for a ...]`, you would be unnecessarily constructing 2 lists with your approach and it is generally frowned up to use a list comprehension for side effects.